# is it possible to integrate non-AMP consent into AMP as iframe

Tags: amp-html

I am stuck at implementing AMP consent screen like non-AMP, somehow AMP not support granular selection and i am using usercentrics vendor for non-AMP which i can also use usercentrics in AMP but not looking exactly like non-AMP, is it possible to make non-AMP consent screen as iframe and integrate into AMP?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do the words mean: `granular selection`

Comment: i mean select essential, marketing as optional to user, instead of we can only do weather user accept all or deny, those two options we have